# getSymbols returning inaccurate data

Tags: r, quantmod, stockquotes

For some reason getSymbols is returning inaccurate data for the below symbol. Example for this data in the high column the price went from 35 to 3515 between 2021 feb and 2021 march 16th.

```
d <-  as.data.frame(
     getSymbols(
         paste("USHAMART" , ".NS", sep = ""),
         from ="2000-01-01", 
         periodicity = "weekly" ,
         return.class = 'zoo',
         env = NULL
     )
 )
```

Not sure if this is occurring for other symbols but I doubt it may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crapy data on yahoo finance. What a surprise. You get "free" data and this is an example of errors that can occur. Looks like you need to divide the numbers that are in the thousands by 100 to get the "correct" data.

See the data disclaimers on Yahoo:

> All data provided on Yahoo Finance is provided for informational
> purposes only, and is not intended for trading or investing purposes.

Comment: Is it same with Google finance?

Comment: @Stupid_Intern, `getSymbols` no longer works with google finance.

Comment: Ohh any other reliable source of data?

Comment: try alphavantage